# Monkey Test logging with time stamp of monkey event injection or abort

Tags: android, testing, monkey-testing

How can i get the timestamp of monkey event injection or the time stamp when monkey aborted. 
Currently, i am using the command:

`adb shell monkey -s 14587 -p com.example.myApp 1000000 -v -v -v --ignore-timeouts --ignore-crashes --ignore-security-exceptions --throttle 500 >> MonkeyTest.txt`

Please let me know if anything extra i need to add in this command to get the timestamp.

Also, if possible could you please give me monkey test cheat sheet if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have went through the Android developer console and i got the list of monkey commands. But I am not able to fined the exact option to have time-stamp in the monkey log.

[Monkey commands and options](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html)

But, I have fount an alteranative for this. I can have logcat for the device parallely while monky is running.

Wrote following command in another command prompt as:

```
adb logcat >> MonkeyTest_DeviceLog.txt
```

This gave me entire device log while monkey test is going on our application. Here i am able to find the ANR, exceptions, and errors related to our applications as well as dependent application as well.